# why is not case sensitive if I have a collation that is set as CS?

Tags: sql-server, collation, case-sensitive

I have installed SQL Server Express 2008 R2 and in the installation I set the collation to Modern_Spanish_CS_AS.

In SQL Server Management Studio I can see that the server has this collation and my data base too, however, when I query and in the where I set a string as condition, I get the same result when I use upper or lower strings.

This is a new installation, but I remember that in my last installation, this works.

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is the create  table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios](
    [IDUsuario] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NombreUsuario] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Usuarios] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IDUsuario] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_NombreUsuario] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [NombreUsuario] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

this is the query:

```
select * from Usuarios where NombreUsuario = 'USUARIO01';
select * from Usuarios where NombreUsuario = 'Usuario01';
```

Both queries return the same registers.

EDIT 2:

I execute this query:

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') DBCollation,collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Usuarios]') AND name = 'NombreUsuario'
```

The result is:

```
DB_COllation: Modern_Spanish_CS_AS
CollationName: Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
```

Comment: Does the table definition contain collation hints? Is that the default collation for this database?

Comment: If I go to the properties of my database the collation is CS_AS, the same collation that has the server.

Comment: Individual columns have collations too - have you checked the column's collation?

Comment: In the extended propeperties of the  collumn has the same collation, CS_AS.

Comment: You might need to show the query too. From [Collation precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886(v=sql.90).aspx): "Operators and functions are either collation sensitive or insensitive." - that is, not every possible function or operator actually respects collations.

Comment: Can you script out the `CREATE TABLE` and add it to your question along with the query.

Comment: I edit with the create table script and the queries that I use.

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') DBCollation,collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Usuarios]') AND name = 'NombreUsuario'`?

Comment: I have added the query and the result to the main post.

Comment: So it looks like the column's collation is `CI_AS`, not `CS_AS` after all.

Comment: And Could I change de collation of all the database?. I would like that all the columns of all the tables are CS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the server or a databases collation has no effect on any existing objects - they retain whatever collation settings were specified/were the default at the time that they were created.

To alter your existing column, you would do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Usuarios
    ALTER COLUMN NombreUsuario
        [varchar](200) collate Modern_Spanish_CS_AS NULL
```

To find all columns that you need to alter:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns where collation_name <> 'Modern_Spanish_CS_AS'
       and OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,N'IsMSShipped')=0
```

(Which, helpfully, won't return non textual columns since they have a collation of `NULL`)